# How to get the active Directory details from single Sign on?

Tags: c#, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

we have an active directory in Azure. I want to know if there is any way we can get the details of the users who logged into the system using single sign on , such as User ID, Display name, email address etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will be able to get user details and identity provider details.
[That page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/) provides details information on what you get and how you get it from Azure Active Directory.